# PHP echo objects from an XML document where there are duplicate nodes

Tags: php, xml

I have been using the [Bing Maps API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441726.aspx)  to get traffic incidents from a certain area.  This would then create an XML document, I can access objects that are single nodes but can't echo any nodes that are nested within other nodes.  The XML document looks like:

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
<Copyright>
 - Message -
</Copyright>
<BrandLogoUri>
  - Logo -
 </BrandLogoUri>
 <StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
 <StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
 <AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
 <TraceId>
  - Trace ID- 
 </TraceId>
 <ResourceSets>
 <ResourceSet>
 <EstimatedTotal>1</EstimatedTotal>
 <Resources>
 <TrafficIncident>
 <Point>
 <Latitude> - Latitude - </Latitude>
 <Longitude>- Longitude -</Longitude>
 </Point>
 <IncidentId>- IncidentId -</IncidentId>
 <LastModifiedUTC>- Time -</LastModifiedUTC>
 <StartTimeUTC>- Time -</StartTimeUTC>
 <EndTimeUTC>- Time -</EndTimeUTC>
 <Type>- Type -</Type>
 <Severity>- Severity -</Severity>
 <Verified>- True -</Verified>
 <RoadClosed>- True -</RoadClosed>
 <Description>
  - Description - 
 </Description>
 <ToPoint>
 <Latitude>-Latitude -</Latitude>
 <Longitude>- Longitude -</Longitude>
 </ToPoint>
 </TrafficIncident>
 </Resources>
 </ResourceSet>
 </ResourceSets>
 </Response>
```

To echo the objects in a single node I have been using the following PHP Code:

```
<?php 
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("link");
    echo "Trace Id <br>";
    echo $xml->TraceId . "<br>";
    echo $xml->Copyright . "<br>";
    echo $xml->Verified . "<br>";
?>
```

To echo the Latitude which is in a nested node I have tried the PHP code:

```
    foreach( $xml->TrafficIncident->Point->Latitude as $row ){
        echo'<td>'.$row.'</td>';
    }
```

But so far no luck.  Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: I think your XML path is wrong, hard to say without code formatting though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($xml->ResourceSets->ResourceSet->Resources->TrafficIncident as $trafficIncident)
{
   echo $trafficIncident->Point->Latitude.' '.$trafficIncident->Point->Longitude;
}
```